# With Facebooker2, can I use apprequests_create on backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm trying to send apprequest on the backend, here is the code I'm trying to do it, but it always return 'Mogli::Client::HTTPException' error. My question is (1) can I do it on backend? (2) what kind of permission should I acquire ? (3) what is the correct way to use the apprequest_create?

Thank you and following is the code i'm trying to use:

```
friend = Mogli::User.find(friend_facebook_id.to_i, current_facebook_client)
friend.apprequests_create(
            Mogli::AppRequest.new(
                            :link=>"callback url",
                            :to => {:id => friend_facebook_id, :name => friend_facebook_name},,
                            :message=>"Try 1"))
```

Here is the application trace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mogli-0.0.30/lib/mogli/client.rb:215:in `raise_error_if_necessary'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mogli-0.0.30/lib/mogli/client.rb:151:in `map_data'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mogli-0.0.30/lib/mogli/client.rb:116:in `post'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mogli-0.0.30/lib/mogli/model.rb:113:in `apprequests_create'
```

Comment: The HTTPException itself isn't terribly useful, is there another error message inside the Exception? Something from the Facebook API perhaps?

Comment: My first thought is I don't get the correct permission, because when I test the feed_create method, it returns the same error, then I accquire the 'create_note' permission, and it works. But I didn't find any permission allow me to create apprequests.

Comment: So you're trying to send an app -> user request? Check the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/ (search for 'App-generated request') - if this is what you're doing the most likely problem is that you're using a user access token and not your application access token

Comment: Not exactly, what I want to do is to invite friends to our application, which means those friends haven't grant us any permission. So I think it still a user request, but I want to do not using the facebook dialog, but provide our own invite button, and once our user click the invite button, the apprequest could be send out in the backend.

Comment: No, there's no API to create user-user requests, you'll need to use the request dialog (instructions are on the same link above) - if you need to track whether the user has invited specific people, use the callback from that dialog to get the request IDs and check the requests in the graph API

Comment: ic, thank you. yes, I could send request with the dialog but the layout is not exactly what I want, that's why I want to do my own frontend and send the request at the backend.